# Auto Increment in MS SQL letter and number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one question, how to achieve auto increment in MS SQL. the one way i know so far is to perfix in the table eg

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CUSId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,CUSKey AS 'Cus' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CUSId), 6) PERSISTED
    ,CusName VARCHAR(50)
    ,mobileno INT
    ,Gender VARCHAR(10)
    )
```

---

i will get something like

```
Cus0001
Cus0002
```

what after Cus9999 ?

some how can i achive auto increment like this

```
CUSAB000001
CUSAB000002
CUSAB000003
CUSAB000004
CUSAB000005
CUSAB000006
CUSAB000007
CUSAB000008
CUSAB999999
CUSCD000001
CUSYZ999999.
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to increment groups starting at `AA` and ending at `ZZ`, you need to convert the left portion of the number (whatever is above the number of digits you want to keep as integers) into Base 26. You start by truncating the right portion of the number so that you have only the left portion, then you divide by 10 ^ IntegerDigits (e.g. 3 integer digits == 10 ^ 3 == 1000) to get the `A_` side, then use modulo on the same 10 ^ IntegerDigits to get the `_A` side. Those values will get us the offset from the ASCII value for `A`. For example:

```
SELECT (123142 / 1000) AS [Truncated],
       (123142 / 1000) / 26 AS [SetsOf26],
       (123142 / 1000) % 26 AS [Remaining],
       CHAR(65) AS [A];

-- Truncated = 123
-- SetsOf26  = 4
-- Remaining = 19
-- A         = A
```

We can put all of that together in an Inline TVF (for demo purposes, not for using in a computed column in a table) as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Base26 (@Base10 INT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
  WITH truncated AS
  (
    SELECT (@Base10 / 1000) AS [Value]
  )
  SELECT @Base10 AS [Actual],
    tr.Value AS [Truncated],
    CHAR(65 + (tr.Value / 26)) AS [1stChar],
    CHAR(65 + (tr.Value % 26)) AS [2ndChar],
    CHAR(65 + (tr.Value / 26))
      + CHAR(65 + (tr.Value % 26))
      + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @Base10 % 1000), 3) AS [EndResult]
  FROM truncated tr;
GO
```

Then we can test with:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Base26(142);
SELECT * FROM dbo.Base26(3142);
SELECT * FROM dbo.Base26(123142);
SELECT * FROM dbo.Base26(123999);
```

which returns:

```
Actual   Truncated   1stChar   2ndChar   EndResult
142      0           A         A         AA142

3142     3           A         D         AD142

123142   123         E         T         ET142

123999   123         E         T         ET999
```

**HOWEVER,** I see absolutely *no* reason at all to implement this in your situation. There is no benefit in having a string "CusXXXXXX" value where "XXXXXX" is really just the `IDENTITY` value. If you were going to obfuscate the "XXXXXX" via a hash or Modular Multiplicative Inverse, then it might be ok, though I am still not sure you would want to store the "Cus" string portion of it. But in its current form, you get no benefit whatsoever from doing this. You are just wasting space in the DB.

Other notes:

- You would be better off *not* abbreviating "Customer" to be "CUS" as a prefix for columns in this table. Just use the full table name, especially for the ID column: `CustomerID`, and `CustomerName`.
- You should not use a numeric type (i.e. `INT`) to store phone numbers. Numbers that you do not do mathematical operations on should be stored as strings. This also applies to postal codes, Social Security Numbers (SSNs), etc. In the case of phone numbers, they often have extensions or other non-numeric options, such as prefixing with `+` if they are outside of the base country.
- You should not use a string type (i.e. `VARCHAR(10)`) to store a repeated code / label such as "gender" (assuming that the full words "male" and "female" or similar are being stored, and that a non-binary / `_BIN2` Collation is being used). You should have a "Gender" lookup table with a `GenderID TINYINT` column as the Primary Key (but *not* an `IDENTITY`). Then in the `Customer` table you would also have `GenderID TINYINT` but it would be a Foreign Key referencing `dbo.Gender (GenderID)`.

  OR:

  You could use a `CHAR(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL` column with a `CHECK` Constraint enforcing that only `M` and `F` are acceptable. This gets you a "code" that is human readable while still being as efficient with storage, memory, and comparisons as a `TINYINT` would be.

Comment: cannot agree more with what you said  " I see absolutely no reason at all to implement this in your situation. There is no benefit in having a string "CusXXXXXX" value where "XXXXXX" is really just the IDENTITY value"

Comment: I cannot agree with the Gender idea. A tinyint is one byte; so is CHAR(1). I cannot imagine needing 26 genders. Even CHAR(6) to support spelling out some genders is not going to be particularly burdensome in space consumed, compared with the CPU overhead of relating it to another table.

Comment: @RossPresser `CHAR(1)` would work _if_ using a binary (i.e. `_BIN2`) Collation (I had forgotten about that option). And in that case then there wouldn't been an explicit need for the lookup table. But there are at least two major issues, sometimes three, with what you are suggesting: 1) space does matter as the number of rows grows, even more so if indexing the column -- larger table = longer to read from disk and more buffer pool used to store the pages in memory, 2) case insensitive string comparisons, even if just 1 letter, are slower than a 1 byte binary comparison,  (continued)

Comment: @RossPresser yet another problem that grows as the number of rows increases, and 3) if using the words, then you run into differences in spellings -- this is one of the problems that normalization addresses. So yes, spelling out the full words in either `CHAR(6)` or `VARCHAR(6)` is incredibly worse than using either `TINYINT` or `CHAR(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`.

Comment: In the extreme case, your line of attack would mean extracting all postal codes to a separate table and using a SMALLINT primary key. After all, 2 bytes for SMALLINT occupy less space than 5 chars for ZIP or 9 for ZIP+4! You have to draw a line somewhere between space efficiency and expressibility. I choose to draw it above the line of Gender and PostalCode.

Comment: CHECK constraints for a well-defined field like Gender are infinitely preferable to a separate table. In my opinion. Which may not be worth anything but has kept me employed for 20 years.

Comment: The only reason I proposed multiple character field for Gender was if you needed to express things like "born intersex, currently pre-op, transitioning to female" or something ridiculous like that. One character could encode it -- again, there's no way you have more than 256 genders to encode -- but it would be essentially meaningless without a lookup table. Which I would probably support if you really needed to encode such things.

Comment: @RossPresser Postal Codes aren't analogous to a "type" like gender. If you want expressibility then the `CHAR(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2` option gets that with the same efficiency of storage and comparison as the `TINYINT`. Yes, a `CHECK` Constraint will take care of problem #3, but not problems #1 and #2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43710/discussion-between-ross-presser-and-srutzky).

Answer (score 2):

Read this excellent article please.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

Note that the dbID column is standard, database-generated identity which will be our physical primary key of the table. However, we will add a CustomerNumber column which will be what we expose to the outside world in the "C0000" format, as described.

Let's create a function accepts an integer, and uses that integer to return our CustomerNumber:

```
create function CustomerNumber (@id int) 
returns char(5) 
as 
begin 
return 'C' + right('0000' + convert(varchar(10), @id), 4) 
end
```

Using that function, we can simply add a computed column to our table like this:

```
alter table Customers add CustomerNumber as dbo.CustomerNumber(dbID)
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question, which is how to handle incrementing past a particular fixed range of digits.